# Are there any Redshift system tables that show how many records were loaded in a COPY statement?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I can't find any system tables, even with joining several together, that have info to show how many records were loaded with a `COPY` statement. I've looked at a bunch of tables in the `pg_catalog` schema but haven't found anything

Comment: Does your each line from the load file make 1 row? I mean, do you use new line character for new row and do you use MAXERROR in copy command?

Answer (score 1):

The system table `STL_LOAD_COMMITS` shows how many records were loaded **per file** but it does not provide a simple way to associate the load to the table being loaded (only `query_id` is provided).

However `COPY` returns the loaded row count to the client in a consistent way that can be captured and parsed. For example:

```
INFO:  Load into table 'my_table' completed, 7304953 record(s) loaded successfully.
```

I submit my loads in a bash script and capture this return line. For instance, with my `COPY` statement in a variable called `sql`:

```
copy=`psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -h $3 -d "$4" -c "$sql"`;
```

A new variable `copy` will be created that contains the `INFO…` line.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using new line character as a new row in your load file, you can query table STL_LOAD_COMMITS and check the lines_scanned columns, which gives you the number of rows copied in the table.